# How to fix warning 'sprintf' swriting a termination nul past the end ot the destination [-Wformat-overflow=]

Tags: c

Below is my code and when I compile this, warning comes up ..

Please let me know how to fix it

```
sprintf(gsErrLog.aPrgmNm, "%-15.15s", pzArgv[0]);
                          ^
char gsErrLog.aPrgmNm [15];
```

> warning: 'sprintf' writing a termination nul past the end of the destination [-Wformat-overflow=]

Comment: What is `zFindStr`?

Comment: Always use `snprintf` to make sure you never get buffer overflows.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: How large is your desination buffer?

Comment: Is `%03s` a legitimate format specifier? I'd bet dollars to donuts that's supposed to be `%03d`... And, the parameter is being interpreted as an address of an 8 mile long string somewhere off in UB-land...

Comment: I updated my code. 
gsErrLog.aPrgmNm char buffer size is 15.

Comment: You *do* remember that strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*? And that a string with 15 characters really need space for 16, to be able to contain the null-terminator?

Comment: And, the newly appearing `pzArgv[0]` probably wants to be either `pzArgv` or `&pzArgv[0]`... (Beginning to feel like a game of "Whack-a-Mole" `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

```
char gsErrLog.aPrgmNm [15];
sprintf(gsErrLog.aPrgmNm, "%-15.15s", pzArgv[0]);
```

Do this:

```
char gsErrLog.aPrgmNm [16];
snprintf(gsErrLog.aPrgmNm, sizeof(gsErrLog.aPrgmNm), "%-15.15s", pzArgv[0]);
```

- A 15 length sprintf() doesn’t have enough space to store in a 15
  character array of char. You will need room for the null (\0) at the
  end.
- Always use snprintf(), as it permits a limitation on how many characters to write.